# UITableView - code inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am developing one universal application. In that I am using the `UITableView`.I created that one dynamically. And i written the below code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.But it's not moving to next page. Please tell me how to do this one.

```
FirstViewController *fst =[[FirstViewController alloc]init]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fst animated:YES];
```

Comment: What is your problem ViewController or tableView ?

Comment: I don't think its the table which is the problem. It is already loaded.

Comment: Put a break point in your didSelectROwAtIndexpath method. and check weather the control is reaching at this point or not.

Comment: It was going to didselectrow method.But it was not mving to next view.

Comment: check your . xib for the connections of delegate and datasource.
Declare <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> in .h file
Also refer to @Nitish 's answer
If it is still not working, post some more coding in your question

Comment: make sure that your current `UIViewController` is put on `UINavigationController`. if it's existing by itself, pushing will not work..

Comment: @user1498119 I think you need to consider reading some of the documentation and tutorials that Apple (and others) provide for doing iOS app development. You seem to be trying to build something too advanced before you have mastered the basics.

Comment: @demon9733 is right; if the current UIViewController isn't a child of a UINavigationController, then self.navigationController is nil and the push attempt will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give reference of the nil file here.

```
FirstViewController *fst =[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"abc.xib"]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fst animated:YES];
```

Comment: You do not need to reference the .xib file if it has the same name as the view controller class.  Assuming you have FirstViewController.xib, then [[FirstViewController alloc] init] internally calls [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController"];